# What locks does SQL Server take during a merge statement

Tags: t-sql, merge

When I use a `merge` statement in T-SQL, what locks are taken by SQL Server? Does it do row locks or table locks if it is updating many rows?

Comment: Before using `merge`, read Aaron Bertrand's [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). For some lock information, read Dan Guzman's [“UPSERT” Race Condition With MERGE](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/01/31/upsert-race-condition-with-merge/).

Comment: Great articles - thanks.